How to download a "sequence" of elliptic curves on LMFDB database
I apologize if this question is not appropriate for this platform. I am working on specific problems involving elliptic curves and am looking for numerical examples. The LMFDB database has been quite helpful in this regard.
My question: Given a sequence of elliptic curves $\{E_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}_{> 0}}$, where each curve has an explicitly known Weierstrass equation, how can I download information for this entire sequence of elliptic curves at once (for a large but finite number of them)?
What I’ve tried: On LMFDB, I can search for all elliptic curves with a fixed conductor $N$ and download the information in a single .txt file, which I can then process using Python or another programming language. However, when it comes to a sequence of elliptic curves with specific Weierstrass equations, I have only been able to input each equation individually and manually record the information into an Excel file. I am hoping there is a more efficient method for this.
Thank you so much for your help!

To the close voters: this is a question about how to use a specific mathematical resource to solve a specific mathematical question. The motivation is clear and the question is well asked. Moreover, there are users on this site who work with the LMFDB and can answer this question.

I've never actually worked with it, but the LMFDB has an API that I guess is probably the right way to do this!

I second using the API. There is also a new experimental Python interface called lmfdb-lite. Alternatively, if you want to do many intensive queries, you can fork the LMFDB Github repo and interact with the database using SageMath. In either case, you would probably take your elliptic curves, compute their minimal models, and then query the database for curves with those coefficients.

As an aside, if your question is not deemed to be within the scope of math.se, you can also ask questions or submit feedback to the LMFDB here.

If you request this information from the LMFDB you can choose the format you download! Where you were seeing "download" it then says "displayed columns for all results to [text]" where [text] is actually a drop-down menu. There you can select your favourite computer algebra format
